# Are there any opensource PHP cryptocurrency exchange/marketplace

Tags: exchanges, trading, php, open-source

As the title suggest, are there any opensource PHP cryptocurrency exchange/marketplace.

Most of the ones I found does not seem to work or are abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any and I believe it's something hard to find, Because exposing PHP codes may lead to some critical exploits and vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is bitwasp: https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/BitWasp . It's actively developed but not yet production ready. This same group also produces a php library which is also found on github: https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this one https://github.com/GMX9/Crypto-Exchange-PHP
Is based from shapeshift, instant exchange that you can use freely

Answer (score 0):

Well its not really a exchange platform but it supports apis of more than such exchange platforms,big name include Binance, Bittrex etc . Also try it if you are looking for trading purpose
Check this out

> https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt